# オブジェクトをフェードインフェードアウトさせる方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

UnityでVRコンテンツを作っています。
1つのシーンの中にオブジェクトを2つおき、コントローラーのトリガーでオブジェクトの表示非表示を切り替えています。
例えば、トリガーを引いているときはAは見えているけどBは見えていない、
トリガーを離しているときはBは見えているけどAは見えていない
というように実装しています。

今やりたいこととしてはこのオブジェクトの表示非表示を切り替えるときにフェードインフェードアウトをつけたいと思っています。
スクリプトをどのように書けばよいのでしょうか？

ちなみに今のオブジェクトの表示非表示はコントローラーに

```
objBall.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
```

などと書いたスクリプトを割り当てることで実装しています。
これにフェードイン・アウトの効果をつけたいです。
シーンは1つのシーンの中で行いたいと考えています。